# Quadrics over the univariate function field with discriminant of minimal degree

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, computational-number-theory, computer-algebra

Consider a non-degenerate quadric $Q(x,y,z) \subset \mathrm{P}^2$ over the univariate function field $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$, where $\mathbb{F}_p$ is a prime finite field, $p > 2$. For simplicity assume that coefficients of $Q$ lie in $\mathbb{F}_p[t]$.

Let $\Delta_Q(t) \in \mathbb{F}_p[t]$ be the discriminant of $Q$, i.e., the determinant of the corresponding symmetric matrix.

How to understand is there or not (at least in some cases) a quadric $Q^\prime$ isomorphic over $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$ to $Q$ such that the polynomial $\Delta_{Q^\prime}(t)$ has strictly smaller degree than $\Delta_Q(t)$. And how can I explicitly construct a linear transformation (over $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$) between $Q$ and $Q^\prime$?

Comment: A constant quadric has degree $0$, i.e., if the coefficients of $Q$ are elements of $\mathbb{F}_p$ and if the quadric is nondegenerated in $\mathbb{F}_p[x,y,z]_2$, then the discriminant is a nonzero element in $\mathbb{F}_p$.  There can be no smaller degree than zero.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Yes, but this is a trivial case.

Comment: There is an article by Alessio Corti on this.  I will find the precise reference later.

Comment: I see now that the article of Corti appears to apply on in the case of curves and surfaces.  Here is the link: https://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9505036

Comment: I see that you are, indeed, asking only about plane conics.  Thus, Corti's paper  does apply to  your situation.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what page in this article I should look.

Comment: I guess the first page in the article that describes "minimal models" of conic  bundles is p. 5, namely Theorem 1.7.

Comment: Thank you, but I think this article is not very appropriate for my question. If I am right, Corti considers conics over surfaces. Hence there should be more elementary answer for my question.

Comment: Certainly Corti considers more complicated Mori fiber spaces than conic bundles.  However, conic bundles are one of the Mori fiber spaces that Corti treats in his article.